# How to mock a C++ function in Objective C testing

Tags: c++, objective-c, unit-testing, mockito, ocmock

I am trying to write test case for an objective-C function that uses a C++ function with return type bool. Inside the Objective-C function, I am simply calling the C++ function in a conditional statement as `if(CppClass::CppFunction)` and proceeding accordingly. For writing the test for the said objective-C function, I need to mock the CppFunction. I am not able to do that with OCMock. What is the correct way of mocking the C++ function?

Comment: Wrap C++ API with simple objective-C code and mock the wrapper in the way you usually do this. Note  that in the future you may consider replace this C++ dependency with something else which could be objective-C or swift code.

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill if you're really just trying to mock one C++ function, but you can try using [Mimicc](https://mimicc.dev)

Run it on the header which declares the C++ code you want to mock and pass the same command line arguments that you would to the clang invocation you use to compile the code.